# Send variables to router in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js, I have some variable like

```
var user = "max";
```

and a route function

```
app.post('/register', user.postRegister);
```

and in my /routes/user.js I have a module function like this

```
exports.postRegister = function(req, res){
   // how do get the user variable from here?
}
```

Comment: it depends...is this a realistic example? Why is the variable there (hardcoded?) in first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with a closure, like so:

```
app.post('/register', user.postRegister(user));

exports.postRegister = function(user) {
  return function(req, res){
    // now you have user here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial function so the username will be passed as first argument to your handler:

```
// app.js
var userName = 'max';
app.post('/register', user.postRegister.bind(user, userName));

// routes/user.js
exports.postRegister = function(userName, req, res) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you are want to access the user information in the controllers, if that's the case. Its better to use sessions in this case.

Example:

```
var setSession = function(req, res, next)
{
  req.session.user = "max";
  //Or get the actual user by querying the database
  next();
}
```

then

```
app.post('/register', setSession, user.postRegister(user));

exports.postRegister = function(req, res){
   var user = req.session.user;
}
```